# Python - Can someone please explain why I keep getting correct output, but it keeps saying "none" underneath it

Tags: python

Trying to test my function in the first box of code and i keep getting the correct output I want, but it says "none" underneath it for some reason as you can see in the second box of code, however, Colab does not indicate any errors, yet the program in the third box of code which I have to test it against keeps giving me error message - "Something's not quite right: try checking all the test cases here and make sure your function works for all of them." HELP!

```
def speeding_ticket(speed, limit):
  if speed <= limit:
    _answer = print("ok")
  elif speed >= limit and speed <= limit + 9:
    _answer = print("grace")
  else:
    _answer = print("ticket")
  return _answer
```

I keep getting "none" after output

```
# test your function here
speed = 42
limit = 35
print(speeding_ticket(speed, limit))

grace
None
```

I am testing it against this code

```
    # Run this cell to get feedback on your answer
def test_speeding_ticket(answer):

  student_score = 1

  cases = [
      (35, 55, "ok"),
      (56, 55, "grace"),
      (62, 55, "grace"),
      (73, 55, "ticket"),
      (56, 35, "ticket"),
      (34, 35, "ok"),
      (42, 35, "grace"),
  ]

  for case in cases:
    ref = case[2]
    if answer(case[0], case[1]) != ref:
      student_score = 0

  if student_score == 1:
    print("Correct, great job!")
  else:
    print("Something's not quite right: try checking all the test cases here and make sure your 
function works for all of them")

test_speeding_ticket(speeding_ticket)
```

Comment: @python_user: They really should make their function return the correct thing instead of printing internally.

Answer (score 2):

You're using `print`, which does not `return` what it printed, it returns `None`. So when you `print` the result from your function (`_answer`), that's `None` as well. Change your function to:

```
def speeding_ticket(speed, limit):
  if speed <= limit:
    _answer = "ok"  # No print
  elif speed >= limit and speed <= limit + 9:
    _answer = "grace"  # No print
  else:
    _answer = "ticket"  # No print
  return _answer
```

Comment: Thank you! So essentially I cannot really assign a print() function to a variable?

Comment: `So essentially I cannot really assign a print() function to a variable?` What is this supposed to do? Either you `print` or you `return`. Or do both. But do not `return print`.

Comment: @QuitePlatypus123: I mean, you *can*; after all, you *did*. It's just that it returns `None`, so it's not useful. If you want to `print` and assign, just assign, then `print` what you assigned to it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `print` returns `None`. Assigning `print` to a variable assigns `None`.

```py
def speeding_ticket(speed, limit):
  if speed <= limit:
    answer = "ok"
  elif speed >= limit and speed <= limit + 9:
    answer = "grace"
  else:
    answer = "ticket"
  return answer
```

`None` is the default that functions return. So if you write a function that doesn't return a value, it returns `None`.